# Is there a word that represents the idea of "natural flow"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, when considering the relative velocity of a boat on a river, we consider the "natural flow" of the river when accounting for the adjusted speed.

When you think about a person's day, there is a natural flow in his/her day dictated by their school or work.

In an electric field, there is a natural flow of electric current, and you can generate voltage by going against the grain of this natural flow.

Comment: You should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: [**Current**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/current) works for the first and third examples, as well as for more general events.

Comment: Pretty sure that not how electric fields work

Comment: [**Rhythm**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rhythm) may work for some  other cases. What is "natural" for rivers may not be for people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "electrical current" referred to in the question is derived from the word "current" meaning the flow of water in a river.

> "**current**" noun
>
> Definition of current (Entry 2 of 2)
>
> 1a: the part of a fluid body (such as air or water) moving
> continuously in a certain direction

([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/current))

For example:

> when considering the relative velocity of a boat on a river, we
> consider **the current in** the river when accounting for the adjusted
> speed.

But, this isn't an answer to the whole question.

> When you think about a person's day, there is a natural flow in
> his/her day dictated by their school or work.

Despite the analogy, I don't think that the word "current" would be applicable in this non-physical sense, even though it is applicable in a physical river.

Another word applicable to both water and time, instead of "current". however, might work, which is "**course**" as in "in the course of time, you will learn what it means to be wise."

As another example, one often says that something will be done "in the ordinary course" of one's activities.

Comment: The **current** of opinion, feeling, etc.